# CakePHP 4 Internationalization not working

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-4.x

I have a controller method, which has this line
`I18n::setLocale('de_DE');`.
I also have the following file structure, according to ver.4 documentation.

```
-resources
--locales
---de_DE
----default.po
```

The latter file contains a single translation.
In short, I do everything exactly like Cake tutorial about internationalization says, but message is not translated and stays in English as written in the code.
Is there any additional settings to be made in order to programmatically change interface language?

Comment: Start with clearing your cache like shown here: **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files**

Comment: If clearing the cache doesn't fix it, share a bit of code where you're setting what locale to use, and outputting something that should be translated.

Answer (score 0):

My cakephp code is:

```
public function changeLanguage(){

        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->set('csrfToken', $this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken'));
            $selected = $this->request->getData('language');
            $this->request->getSession()->write('Config.language', $selected);
            I18n::setLocale('de_DE'); //hardcoded just for testing
            return $this->response->withType('application/json')->withStringBody(json_encode(array('status' => 'OK')));
        }
    }

And frontend is JS driven:



function openLangModal(){

    let token = $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val();

    $("#lang-select-btn").unbind();
    $("#lang-select-btn").click(function(){
        var lang = $("#language").val();
        var postUrl = '<path-to-backend>/changeLanguage';

        $.ajax({

            url: postUrl,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {language: lang, _csrfToken: token},
            success: function(data){
                location.href=location.href;
            }
        });
    });
    $("#langModal").modal("show");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).